# Laravel 9.x cannot find the view file

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to send and receive emails from my webpage using mailgun.

Main problem : Laravel cannot find my send-email.blade file on resources\views\pages

I configure my .env file for mailgun.

What I am missing? Here is my codes;

[image: The Error I get]

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/send-email', [App\Http\Controllers\EmailController::class, 'sendEmail']);
```

**app\http\controller\EmailController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\HelloEmail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail()
    {
        $reveiverEmailAddress = "example@gmail.com";

        Mail::to($reveiverEmailAddress)->send(new HelloEmail);

        if (Mail::failures() != 0) {
            return "Email has been sent successfully.";
        }
        return "Oops! There was some error sending the email.";
    }
}
```

**config\services.php**

```
 'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ]
```

**config\mail.php**

```
    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
        ],
    ],


  'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@Example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'app name'),
    ],
    'reply_to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@Example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'app name'),
    ],
```

**app\mail\hellomail.php**

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class HelloEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function build()
    {
      
        return $this->from("support@example.com")->view('email-template');
    }
}
```

**email-template.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>
        Demo of sending emails through the Mailgun email service.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `->view('email-template')` shouldn't that be in `resources/views/`?

Comment: `view('email-template')` tries to open `resources/views/email-template.blade.php`, `view('pages.email-template')` tries to open `resources/views/pages/email-template.blade.php`. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views

Comment: thank you for your help I appreciate it. I'll read the docs again and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `->view('email-template);` which looks for the file in `resources/views/{filename}`

You say your `email-template` file is stored in `resources\views\pages`

Therefore you have to use `->view('pages.email-template');` which will look in `resources/views/pages/{filename}`.

Comment: Thank you this is working! Should I delete the question? Is that counted as typo?